# How to output the seconds in datetime-local input?

Tags: html, angularjs, datetime

i have in Html :

```
<input type="datetime-local" step=1 ng-model="end_date" required />
```

and in code (angularJs)

```
$scope.end_date = new Date('2018-11-10 10:11:15');
```

and the output, no matter what i do, is '2018-11-10 10:11:00'.
I really need the seconds. 
What can i do?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the **output**, just display it differently with a filter. Such filter already is in AngularJS, it's called [date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).
Simply select the format that you need (in your case the seconds would be just `'s'`). Here is a demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.end_date = new Date('2018-11-10 10:11:15');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <input type="datetime-local" step=1 ng-model="end_date" required /> 
  <hr>
  {{end_date | date:"s"}}

</div>
```

Comment: :) actualy the problem was the angular varsion. I had an old one. thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use  very handy directive : https://github.com/eight04/angular-datetime
and then :

```
<input datetime="HH:mm:ss"  step=1 ng-model="myDate" required />
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/iOs0mO4ZuTfmm00HGThp?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to make use of Date filter in angularJs.

```
 <span>{{end_date | date:'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}</span>
```

It will display the date with **time:min:second**

If you just want the time use

```
<span>{{end_date | date:'HH:mm:ss'}}</span>
```

Comment: That's not the issue! My problem is the datepicker from HTML

Comment: yeah, so try applying the same filter to the value obtained from datePicker, You should be able to get the seconds. unless i am missing something here?

Comment: as i said @Aleksey Solovey answer, it was my bad, i've used an old version of angular, wich, probalbly, didn't have spport for seconds. THX anyway